# Maltab: copy axes in a gui to a figure

Tags: matlab

I am going to save an image in the GUI to a sperate figure. Some of codes relevant are as follows:

```
axes(handles.axes1); %axes object
subplot(131); imshow(tempData(:,:,1),[]); title('I1');
subplot(132); imshow(tempData(:,:,2),[]); title('I2');
subplot(133); imshow(tempData(:,:,3),[]); title('I3');
%The three images are displayed in the GUI

% saved to a new figure
handles.axes1
figurenew = figure;
copyobj(handles.axes1,figurenew);
```

Then, there is an error when running the code:

```
Error using copyobj
Copyobj cannot create a copy of an invalid handle.
```

Does that means the handle `handle.axes1` no longer exist? Then how to modify the codes to save the displayed image in the GUI?

Comment: @CrisLuengo: that is a typo. I have corrected it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each subplot has its own Axes object.
You can get this Axes object by writing as follow.

```
figure;
axes1 = subplot(131);
```

Then you can copy the object as you wrote.

```
figurenew = figure;
copyobj( axes1, figurenew );
```

Comment: How to make sure the copied images are centered in the new figure? I note the images in the new figures are not aligned as expected